# ng-options based on previous selected value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array like below.

```
$scope.set = [
{"name":"name1", "value":"value1"}
{"name":"name2", "value":"value2"}
{"name":"name3", "value":"value3"}
]
```

I am trying to show the options based on previous selection. for example if i select **name1** then for the next time i don't want to show the selected option. I want to show only remaining two names i.e, name2 and name3.

I'm trying to achieve this by using some filters but it is effecting the model $scope.set

Please help me in this. thanks in advance.

Comment: try this: store the current selected value (say "name1") in a scope variable and then use that as filter...

Comment: create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mohanguntaka/js25x0q9/)

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for you problem can be found here on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w1wrbqv8/1/). I've created something quickly from scratch since your post did not have an original Fiddle.

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Controller">
    Select value : <b>{{myDropDown.name}}</b><br/><br/>
    Showing all other available options:
    <select ng-options="item.name for item in items | filter: {name: '!' + myDropDown.name}" ng-model="myDropDown">
      <option value="">Select other value</option>
    </select>
</div>

function Controller ($scope) {
    $scope.myDropDown = 'one';    
    $scope.items = [
        {"name":"name1", "value":"value1"},
            {"name":"name2", "value":"value2"},
            {"name":"name3", "value":"value3"}
    ];  
}
```

Comment: not working as expected. what if i have multiple selection. See my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mohanguntaka/js25x0q9/).

Comment: Then what do you want to do? A little more information would be useful instead of commenting 'not working as expected'.... A little more descriptive information would help in trying to solve your problem ....

Comment: Sure, I want to display options based on previous value. i have 3 options a).name1, b)name2, c)name3. by default i can see all three options. i have a button to add new row. once i added name1 as first row then for the second row i dont want to display name1, Only i want to show name2 and name3.

Comment: Woow that really helps ... So tell me why the Fiddle i send can't help you any further?

Comment: It is validating only one value at a time. if i select another value it is overriding previous one.

Comment: So if i understand correct, after the third line (each line having a unique item from your list) the options would be empty because i've used them in the above lines? Correct :)?